# Angular form input value undefined

Tags: forms, angular, typescript, angular4-forms

I'm trying to get the value of an input field in my first ever Angular form, but it is always undefined, and I can't figure out why. I'm importing FormsModule correctly, and I can reference the form object fine, so I must be missing something obvious.

My components HTML

```
<form #searchValue='ngForm' class="" (ngSubmit)='submitSearch(searchValue)'>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="search">
  </div>
</form>
```

And my components ts method (Shortened)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'google-search',
  templateUrl: './google.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./google.component.css']
})

export class GoogleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  submitSearch(formData) {
    console.log(this.searching);
    console.log(formData.value.q);    
  }
}
```

Any ideas to why this is?

Comment: Where are you putting the html element that is submitting the form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to mark the input with `ngModel` so angular will know that this is one of form's controls:

```
<input type="text" ngModel name="q" placeholder="search">
```

Or you can define the variable first in your component, and then bind the input to it via `[(ngModel)]` directive:

```
export class GoogleComponent implements OnInit {
  q: string;

  submitSearch() {
    console.log(this.q);
  }
}

<form class="" (ngSubmit)='submitSearch()'>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="q" [(ngModel)]="q" placeholder="search">
  </div>
</form>
```

One way binding (just `[ngModel]="q"`) could be enough if you just want to read the value from input.

Comment: Thinks, I did try your second option moments before posting this, declaring the `q` variable was the part I was missing. Thanks for your time and the straightforward explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Some like this should work..

Maybe you want to read about model [binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview) and [forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms).

**html component**

```
<form #searchValue='ngForm' class="some-css-class" (ngSubmit)='submitSearch()'>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="q" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" placeholder="search">
    <input type="submit" name="btn" placeholder="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

In **component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'google-search',
  templateUrl: './google.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./google.component.css']
})

export class GoogleComponent implements OnInit {

  searchValue: string = '';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  submitSearch() {
    console.log(this.searchValue);
  }
}
```